# Write a string input reverse on assembley

Tags: assembly, input, x86, dos

This is what i've managed to do so far

```
 Data Segment
 str1 db 'String_Reverse','$' 
 strlen1 dw $-str1
 strrev db 20 dup(' ')


 MSG1 DB 10,13,'ENTER ANY STRING :- $'
 MSG2 DB 10,13,'ENTERED STRING IS :- $'
 MSG3 DB 10,13,'REVERSED STRING IS : $'

 MSG4 DB 10,13,'REVERSED STRING IS : $'

 P1 LABEL BYTE
 M1 DB 0FFH
 L2 DB ?
 P11 DB 0FFH DUP ('$')
Data Ends

CUCU MACRO MSG ;MACRO care afiseaza un mesaj dorit
 MOV AH,9
 LEA DX,MSG
 INT 21H
ENDM 

Code Segment
 Assume cs:code, ds:data
 Begin:

 MOV AX,DATA
 MOV DS,AX 

 CUCU MSG1 ;afisare msg1

 LEA DX,P1
 MOV AH,0AH 
 INT 21H

 CUCU MSG2 ; afisare msg2

 CUCU P11 ; afisare string introdus

 CUCU MSG3


 mov ax, data
 mov ds, ax
 mov es, ax
 mov cx, strlen1
 add cx, -2
 lea si, P11
 lea di, strrev
 add si, strlen1
 add si, -2
 L1:
 mov al, [si]
 mov [di], al
 dec si
 inc di
 loop L1
 mov al, [si]
 mov [di], al
 inc di
 mov dl, '$'
 mov [di], dl
 Print:
 mov ah, 09h
 lea dx, strrev
 int 21h
 Exit:
 mov ax, 4c00h
 int 21h
Code Ends
End Begin
```

At the moment i have str1 and it's displayed reversely but i need the P11 variable to be shown reversely that i get from the keyboard. From what i have seen so far i need strlen(P11) but i have no idea how to get that.

Comment: Do you know how to code it in C (without stdlib)? Can you write an algorithm or a flowchart for it? PS: comment your code (in english) especially if you want others to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 LEA DX,P1
 MOV AH,0AH 
 INT 21H
```

This is, where your data come from. So why don't you check [documentation about it](http://spike.scu.edu.au/~barry/interrupts.html#ah0a)?

Before call the memory at `M1` (BTW, why two labels, and both meaningless?) contains:

`FF ?? 24 24 24 24 24 ...` (255 of `0x24 '$'` bytes).

That `??`, I would suggest to set it to `0` ahead of the int call, as you are not providing any "previous input data". `mov byte ptr[dx+1],0` (after `lea`).

When you enter string "AAAB", then the DOS will return in memory this:

`FF 04 41 41 41 42 0D 24 24 24 ...`

So as you can see, you can read the `L2` byte to get actual length of string without CR, or you can do `strlen` function scanning for `13` in buffer.

I'm not sure what was the question, if there is any, but you stated you have no idea, this above should give you at least two ideas how to continue.

As a side note, stop using meaningless labels, it makes very difficult to "read the source", and that's what you will be doing most of the time.

Also when documentation check fails, you can try to reverse engineer it in debugger. For example this memory content after `int 21h` call is sort of self explanatory (but I still prefer to check documentation first). Yet you should be able to breakpoint after the `int 21h` and take a peek at memory. If you are not, you are doing it wrong, and get some debugger + learn how to use it.